# Thoughts on the most elegant way to structure complex css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here's an example of some markup:

```
<div class="document">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="title" />
    <div class="description />
  </div>
  <div class="sections">
    <div class="section">
       <div class="title" />
       <div class="description" />
    </div>
    <div class="section">
       <div class="title" />
       <div class="description" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my stylesheets, my rules might then look like this:

```
.document .main .title { ... }
.document .sections .section .description { ... }
```

I like this.  This approach has always worked well for me, and I think the increasingly specific selectors make it very clear what is what (almost like reading a sentence).

Recently however I was told that this approach is bad, and that I should do something like the following instead:

```
<div class="document">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="mainTitle" />
    <div class="mainDescription />
  </div>
  <div class="sections">
    <div class="section">
       <div class="sectionTitle" />
       <div class="sectionDescription" />
    </div>
    <div class="section">
       <div class="sectionTitle" />
       <div class="sectionDescription" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The reason is that it avoids any ambiguity in what the class 'title' refers to.

I am curious what people here think?  Is my approach bad (ie confusing, problematic) ?  Is there a preferred way to format css for complex markup?

Comment: Why is that ambiguity a bad thing, when it can be resolved by context when necessary?

Comment: As long as your project is small (<10 different template pages for example), your current way of writing CSS selectors is manageable, if you're careful. If you constantly need to cancel previously written instructions each time you reuse a class or have veeery long selectors, then you're losing time and energy and your CSS are inefficient. Check OOCSS and BEM methodologies, especially if you're working on huge projects (or many look-alike projects). I don't like the syntax of BEM classes, but that's only conventions. The idea behind them is GREAT. And may apply to your projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've started to use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) stylesheets and can't recommend them enough. The nested selectors make your code incredibly readable by structuring it like your HTML:

```
.document {
    .main {
        .title {
            ...
        }

        .foo {
            ...
        }
    }

    .sections {
        .section .description {
            ...
        }

        // Same as `.sections.hidden`
        &.hidden {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

As for your HTML, there's no need to be redundant. The `title` class refers to an element that acts as a title and the type of title can be inferred by looking at the parent element. There's really no benefit from using the long names if you don't find them appealing.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I am not extremely experienced with CSS, but you want to balance readability and compression. The way you used to do it was heavy on compression, and the way you're saying you were suggested to do it seems heavy on readability. But I've tried that latter one, and boy, is that a lot of work. And it barely adds readability, as most things in CSS don't only show up in one place in any given site structure-- they show up in multiple places, making it impossible for that structure you were suggested to actually become readable.

If you ask me, nothing beats a good comment.

//*  If you're trying to be able to easily locate sections of CSS, titles that draw a lot of attention to themselves even if you're skimming very quickly are the way to go*//

Sure beats all the work of tabbing your CSS. And like I said earlier, the reusable nature of CSS declarations makes tabbing impossible to easily follow anyway.